# Wordpress Theme Footer Copyright Editing

Tags: wordpress

I am using the Donovan theme on my WordPress-based website. However, I want to edit the Copyright information in the footer, but I can't find which .php file it's located in. The website in question is: https://mesleksahibi.net/
I've checked the footer.php file, but there is no Copyright information there.

I've checked the contents of the footer.php and functions.php files, but I couldn't find any code that allows me to edit the Copyright text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in `footer.php` you see:

```
<?php donovan_credit_link(); ?>
```

The copyright information is defined in this function on line 426 of `template-tags.php`.

Please make sure that editing this information is not against the terms of use. I just checked the company's [terms and conditions page](https://themezee.com/terms/) and couldn't find anything, but please double check.